# How to get reference to a trigger box

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

In a simple level I have a trigger box with event dispatcher that is called on event `ActorBeginOverlap`. I have in the same level a cube blue print and I want to assign the event dispatcher of the trigger box to the event `BeginPlay` of the cube so I tried like in the picture but it does not work so what is the correct way to do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the object you want to cast to `MyTriggerBox_Blueprint`

Answer (score 0):

You have to get which instance of that triggerBox you want, If you have 50 of them in a level, you have to specify which one you want to cast to. If you have only 1 of them in a level and you want to only talk to that one then use GetActorsOfAllClass then get( a copy) 0 of that array and plug it in as the object